# How move backwards in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse

Lets say I have the string "Lamps", it gets passed into my program and each character is stored into a node in a linked list.

I need to copy that list in reverse order using another linked list, how do I do this, I've gotten pretty far, but how do I move backwards in the linked list ?

You will see the line commented on what I need to put there to move backwards in the linked list.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct NODE {
    struct NODE *next;  
    char data;

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int i;

struct NODE *head;
struct NODE *current;
struct NODE *head2;
struct NODE *current2;
struct NODE *finger;


for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);

head = (struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    current = head;


    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof(argv[1]) - 1; i++ ) {

    current -> data = argv[1][i];
    current -> next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    current = current -> next;
    current -> next = NULL;

}


head2 = (struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    current2 = head2;

    while ( current != head) {

        finger = head;


    while (finger -> next != current) 

        finger = finger -> next;
        current2 -> data = current -> data;
        current2 -> next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
        current2 = current2 -> next;    
        // move backwards



    } // ends loop



}






return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

> How do I move backwards in the (singly) linked list ?

You don't. The trick to reversing one list into another is inserting at the head, rather than at the back, of the target list. You need to traverse your original list in the regular way by following the `next` pointers, but rather than adding elements to the end of the target list, create a new node, and replace the header of the target with it.

Here is a step-by-step illustration:

```
sourceHead -> "A" -> "B" -> "C" -> NULL
your pointer   ^
targetHead -> NULL

sourceHead -> "A" -> "B" -> "C" -> NULL
your pointer          ^
targetHead -> "A" -> NULL

sourceHead -> "A" -> "B" -> "C" -> NULL
your pointer                 ^
targetHead -> "B" -> "A" -> NULL

sourceHead -> "A" -> "B" -> "C" -> NULL
your pointer                        ^
targetHead -> "C" -> "B" -> "A" -> NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

The short version is to extend your struct with a prev variable, when you create a child you assign self to it's Parent variable, and thus you can later, from the child read it's parent variable to move one backward - and recurse to get all the way to the top.

Comment: This would no longer be a linked list